# jQuery: Getting the value of a text input form using .val() doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, input

I'm trying to access the value of an input field of a form.

**The text input of the form is:**

```
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email">
```

**And in my JS file I tried this:**

```
var avisoPago = {
  email: function () {  
    return $('#email').val();   
  },    
...
```

If I try to print out in the console the email value with `email` or `this.email`:

**I get this result:**

In the case of ***email***: `[object HTMLInputElement]`
In the case of ***this.email***: `function () { $('#email').val();  }`

Now if the user types john@example.com how may I get that value in order to use it? (I want to insert that value later on into a MongoDB file).

Comment: Try `avisoPago.email()` (the parenthesis are important if you want to execute that function)

Comment: try to execute the method like, this.email()

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've just tried that and it's the same result as this.email

Comment: THANKS! You were right,  this.email()  worked.

Comment: Also, check that you don't have more than one html element with the id="email"...